# Resaltar texto en resultado de busqueda

Tags: mysql, php5

Me esta dando este error:

> "Fatal error: Cannot redeclare pintar() (previously declared in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\ciecfinal\respuestas.php:25) in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\ciecfinal\respuestas.php on line 25"

Ya intente buscar como resolver el error y no lo entiendo, soy aficionado al php, por eso que acudo a ustedes como expertos.
Dejo aquí el codigo por si alguien me puede dar una mano.

```
<?php
          $buscar = $_POST['b'];   
          if(!empty($buscar)) {
                buscar($buscar);
          }
          function buscar($b) {
                $con = mysql_connect('localhost','root', '');
                mysql_select_db('ciec', $con);
              mysql_query("SET character_set_results = 'utf8', character_set_client = 'utf8', character_set_connection = 'utf8', character_set_database = 'utf8', character_set_server = 'utf8'", $con);

                $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM preguntas WHERE pregunta_pre LIKE '%".$b."%' OR respuesta_pre LIKE '%".$b."%'",$con);

                $contar = @mysql_num_rows($sql);

                if($contar == 0){
                      echo "
                      <div class=\"alert alert-danger\" role=\"alert\">
                      No se han encontrado resultados para <b>$b</b>
                    <div>\n";
                }else{
                  while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
                    $pregunta_pre = $row['pregunta_pre'];
                    $respuesta_pre = $row['respuesta_pre'];

        function pintar($buscar, $respuesta_pre) { 
        $claves = explode(" ",$buscar); 
        $clave = array_unique($claves);
        $num = count($clave); 
        for($i=0; $i < $num; $i++) 
        $respuesta_pre = preg_replace("/(".trim($clave[$i]).")/i","<span class='highlight'>\\1</span>",$respuesta_pre);
        return $respuesta_pre; 
    }             

                    echo "<li><strong>$pregunta_pre</strong></li>
    $respuesta_pre<br><br>
    \n";
                }
            }
      }

    ?>
```

Comment: Tienes metida la declaración de la función pintar() dentro de un bucle, por lo que se va a declarar tantas veces como iteraciones tenga este. Una función que se ha declarado no se puede volver a declarar. Saca la función del bucle y arreglarás ese error.

Comment: Gracias por contestar tan rápido, saque la función del bucle pero no pinta la palabra buscada :(

Comment: No pinta la palabra porque a parte de sacar la declaración de la función fuera del bucle, pero antes del mismo, es decir, por encima de la función buscar, debes hacer la llamada dentro del while a la funcion pintar, o no pintará nada. La respuesta de @MikelFerreiro es buena para solucionar tu problema, pero por coherencia yo declaro la función primero y después la llamo, así es mas fácil de leer el código. Un saludo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Saca la función pintar del while (déjala a la par que la función buscar por ejemplo) y mete dentro del while la llamada a `pintar()`. De esta forma:

```
    <?php
          $buscar = $_POST['b'];   
          if(!empty($buscar)) {
                buscar($buscar);
          }
          function buscar($b) {
                $con = mysql_connect('localhost','root', '');
                mysql_select_db('ciec', $con);
              mysql_query("SET character_set_results = 'utf8', character_set_client = 'utf8', character_set_connection = 'utf8', character_set_database = 'utf8', character_set_server = 'utf8'", $con);

                $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM preguntas WHERE pregunta_pre LIKE '%".$b."%' OR respuesta_pre LIKE '%".$b."%'",$con);

                $contar = @mysql_num_rows($sql);

                if($contar == 0){
                      echo "
                      <div class=\"alert alert-danger\" role=\"alert\">
                      No se han encontrado resultados para <b>$b</b>
                    <div>\n";
                }else{
                  while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
                    $pregunta_pre = $row['pregunta_pre'];
                    $respuesta_pre = $row['respuesta_pre'];

                    pintar($b, $respuesta_pre)

                    echo "<li><strong>$pregunta_pre</strong></li>
    $respuesta_pre<br><br>
    \n";
                }
            }
      }
 function pintar($buscar, $respuesta_pre) { 
        $claves = explode(" ",$buscar); 
        $clave = array_unique($claves);
        $num = count($clave); 
        for($i=0; $i < $num; $i++) 
        $respuesta_pre = preg_replace("/(".trim($clave[$i]).")/i","<span class='highlight'>\\1</span>",$respuesta_pre);
        return $respuesta_pre; 
    }             

    ?>
```

Comment: ahora me da error. Con el ; en pintar($buscar, $respuesta_pre); me dice que la Undefined variable: buscar. Me rindo :(

Comment: Igualmente , muchas gracias por querer ayudarme

Comment: He editado la respuesta, creo que me había patinado y tenía que ser $b en vez de $buscar. De todas formas no te desanimes!  Todo es cuestión de probar hasta que se arregle :D

Comment: Bueno ya esta resuelto gracias a todos por el apoyo. No se como pegar el resultado final por si alguien lo necesita resuelto

Comment: Si está resuelto no olvides marcar la respuesta como correcta y si le dejas un +1 ya lo bordas ;)